# AspectJ: polymorphic logging of methods. Pointcut signature issues

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm having issues with a few pointcut signatures inside my aspect.

1.. Messages are entering our system via 2 exposed interfaces(IIncoming, IOutgoing) and then they are processed by a *PartsManager* component like:

`PartsManager pmanager = new PartManagerImpl();
pmanager.process(message);`

`public class PartManagerImpl implements PartsManager{
    public boolean process(Message message){
        //do some messsage processing..
        return true;
    }
}`

2.. All processed messages are then logged via the following aspect.

`@Aspect
public class OldMessageLogging {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(OldMessageLogging.class);
    @Before("execution(* org.company.PartManagerImpl.process(..))")
    public void processMessageCalled(final JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info("Message processed.");
        return;
    }
}`

3.. But, now I want to log processed messages but with one additional information.
Instead of *Message processed.* I want the log entry to become *Incoming message processed.* or *Outgoing message processed*.

4.. So, I have defined two additional interfaces and changed PartManagerImpl.java like this:

`public class PartManagerImpl implements PartsManager, IncommingMessageProcessor, OutgoingMessageProcessor {
    public boolean process(Message message){
            //do some messsage processing..
            return true;
        }
}`


`public interface IncommingMessageProcessor {
        boolean process(Message message);
}
public interface OutgoingMessageProcessor {
        boolean process(Message message);
}`

5.. Now, message processing is performed like this:

`IncommingMessageProcessor inProcessor = new PartManagerImpl();
    inProcessor.process(message);`

`OutgoingMessageProcessor outProcessor = new PartManagerImpl();
    outProcessor.process(message);`

6.. A new aspect was created to reflect my new logging needs.

`@Aspect
public class NewMessageLogging {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(NewMessageLogging.class);
    @Before("execution(* org.company.IncommingMessageProcessor.process(..))")
    public void processIncomingCalled(final JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info("Incoming message processed.");
        return;
    }
    @Before("execution(* org.company.OutgoingMessageProcessor.process(..))")
    public void processOutgoingCalled(final JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info("Outgoing message processed.");
        return;
    }
}`

**THE CATCH:**
Whenever I'm processing a message like `IncommingMessageProcessor inProcessor = new PartManagerImpl(); inProcessor.process(message);` the message is being logged *twice*, once as an incoming and once as an outgoing message.

I have expected only a call to the *processIncomingCalled* method.

But both of my pointcuts were called!

My pointcut signatures are obviously wrong :/

I tried various approaches but to no avail.
Any suggestions?

**SOLUTION**
Changing the `Message` class was not an option in my case, but was an *viable solution*!

I took a different approach to make code changes minimal.

1. The method `public boolean process(Message message)` in both interfaces was renamed to `processIncoming(Message message)` and `processOutgoing(Message message)`.

   `public interface IncommingMessageProcessor {
       boolean processIncoming(Message message); 
   }` 

   `public interface OutgoingMessageProcessor { 
       boolean processOutgoing(Message message); 
   }`
2. PartsManager interface now extends both interfaces `class PartsManager extends IncommingMessageProcessor, OutgoingMessageProcessor {...}`
   And the process(Message message) method is now private but invoked by calls to the inherited methods processIncoming(...) and processOutgoing(...)
   so my pointcuts now target calls to that methods.
3. Altered aspect (changed method names)

   `@Aspect public class NewMessageLogging {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(NewMessageLogging.class);
    @Before("execution(* org.company.PartsManager.processIncoming(..))") 
   public void processIncomingCalled(final JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
       LOGGER.info("Incoming message processed."); 
       return; 
   } 
    @Before("execution(* org.company.PartsManager.processOutgoing(..))") 
    public void processOutgoingCalled(final JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
       LOGGER.info("Outgoing message processed."); 
   return; 
    } 
   }`

Comment: The problem with your pointcut is that you try to differentiate on which interface your PartManagerImpl implements. But since it implements both, *no matter what field you store it in*, both pointcuts will apply. For this to work you have to differentiate the *message*, not the handler, just like you do to decide in _5_. How are the messages defined? Are there two types, like `public class IncomingMessage extends Message implements IIncoming` and `public class OutgoingMessage extends Message implements IOutgoing`?

Comment: Actually they don't, my Message class is just an simple POJO without any special type hierarchy.

Comment: Then it's not clear how your differentiate between an incoming and an outgoing message. Your solution looks fine as well, I would just suggest to either change the logging message to "Processing incoming/outgoing message.", or the pointcut to @After. Otherwise the logging-output 'lies' in that it logs "processed" before that actually happens. Might be nitpicking, but I'm a stickler where logging is concerned. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that incoming messages implement `IIncoming` and outgoing ones implement `IOutgoing`. Then you can try:

```
@Before("execution(* org.company.PartManagerImpl.process(..)) && args(message)")
public void processIncomingCalled(final JoinPoint joinPoint, IIncoming message)
```

and

```
@Before("execution(* org.company.PartManagerImpl.process(..)) && args(message)")
public void processOutgoingCalled(final JoinPoint joinPoint, IOutgoing message)
```

A class implementing two interfaces which both define the same method signature seems very iffy to me and you probably should not do that. If both incoming and outgoing messages are handled by the same message handler (and even the same method) there should only be one interface for the handler. The distinguishing factor should be the messages and their hierarchy/interfaces. That's what the `args`-part of my suggested pointcut is supposed to check for (I don't have access to a compiler with AspectJ at the moment, so I haven't been able to test it myself yet).

Comment: Your suggestions to differentiate through the message and not through the handler was a legitimate solution to my isssue. In the end I took a different approach because of other business logic related decisions. But I will accept your answer as a viable one. Thank you :)

Comment: Yay, thanks! Hopefully it can help other people with similar problems where it's more applicable than yours. :)